# How to do Loopback in array query

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback

I have a table `Conversation` with property :

```
"participants": {
  "type": [
    "object"
  ],
  "required": true
}
```

and the `dataSource` is MongoDb. I inserted data in format:
`{participants:[{userId:1},{userId:2}]}`.
Now I want to find all conversation which userId 1 is in.
What i did is using this filter: `{where:{participants:{userId:1}}}` but it doesn't work like MongoDb query. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this:

```
app.models.Conversation.find({"where":{"participants":{"elemMatch":{"userId":1}}}}, function(err, res){
    console.log(err, res)
})
```